# Is this the correct way to write IF statements in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

```
New$var = ifelse(new$var1 < 10, "a", ifelse (new$var1>10 & new$var1<20, "b", ifelse(new$var1>20 & new$var1 <30, "c", "d")))
```

I wrote the following code and found values of "var" that should be in "a" are actually in "d". "Var1" has no negative values.

But for some reason, when I use the `which` statement, the code seems to run fine.

How is this possible

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible example that anyone can copy and paste into R. It should include all inputs in easily copied form using `dput`, the code and the expected output.  See the guidance at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: Your title is wrong:  those aren't `if statements`, they are `ifelse()` function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting "d" for 10, then, I think you should consider using  "<=" in your first check.

```
New$var = ifelse(new$var1 <= 10, "a", ifelse (new$var1>10 & new$var1<20, "b", ifelse(new$var1>20 & new$var1 <30, "c", "d")))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should get an error with your current code.

Additionally, you have more information than to which R is "listening."

```
# generating random values
set.seed(25)
new = data.frame(var1 = rnorm(n = 25, mean = 20, sd = 10))

# your code
new$var2 = ifelse(new$var1 < 10, "a", 
                 ifelse (new$var1>10 & new$var1<20, "b", 
                         ifelse(new$var1>20 & new$var1 <30, "c", "d")))
# less code, same result
new$var3 = ifelse(new$var1 < 10, "a",
                  ifelse(new$var1 < 20, "b",
                         ifelse(new$var1 < 30, "c",
                                "d")))

# different approach same results
new$var4 = cut(new$var1, breaks = c(min(new$var1),
                                    10, 20, 30,
                                    max(new$var1)),
               labels = letters[1:4],
               include.lowest = T)

# this is cut again, without the labels, so you can see how it works
new$var5 = cut(new$var1, breaks = c(min(new$var1),
                                    10, 20, 30,
                                    max(new$var1)),
               include.lowest = T)

all.equal(new$var2, new$var3)

new
#         var1 var2 var3 var4      var5
# 1  17.881664    b    b    b   (10,20]
# 2   9.584089    a    a    a [2.57,10]
# 3   8.466924    a    a    a [2.57,10]
# 4  23.215315    c    c    c   (20,30]
# 5   4.998701    a    a    a [2.57,10]
# 6  15.544667    b    b    b   (10,20]
# 7  37.340454    d    d    d (30,43.7]
# 8  25.112956    c    c    c   (20,30]
# 9  20.996450    c    c    c   (20,30]
# 10 19.421089    b    b    b   (10,20]
# 11  2.572124    a    a    a [2.57,10]
# 12  6.750470    a    a    a [2.57,10]
# 13 14.520661    b    b    b   (10,20]
# 14  5.436157    a    a    a [2.57,10]
# 15 20.826868    c    c    c   (20,30]
# 16 29.275789    c    c    c   (20,30]
# 17 12.832307    b    b    b   (10,20]
# 18 29.623997    c    c    c   (20,30]
# 19 35.458846    d    d    d (30,43.7]
# 20  9.902364    a    a    a [2.57,10]
# 21 25.574109    c    c    c   (20,30]
# 22 21.687815    c    c    c   (20,30]
# 23 21.552589    c    c    c   (20,30]
# 24 43.677647    d    d    d (30,43.7]
# 25  4.143556    a    a    a [2.57,10]
```